# I need to update my page using Anchor (#) in URL

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, hashchange

**index.php**

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>My Title</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function getLink(data) {
    document.getElementById("box").innerHTML="This is "+data;
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <a href="#home" onClick="getLink('Home')">Home</a><br />
  <a href="#profile" onClick="getLink('Profile')">Profile</a><br />
  <a href="#message" onClick="getLink('Message')">Message</a><br />
  <a href="#setting" onClick="getLink('Setting')">Setting</a><br />
  <hr />
  <div id="box"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Output**

`Home`
`Profile`
`Message`
`Setting`

---

This is Home

---

As the code says my `Div` contents updated when i click any of the `link` but the problem is that when user `goes back` by clicking `Back Button of Browser` the content of my `Div` donot changes.
I want that either user `Goes Back`, `Goes Forward` or he directly puts the path in the `address bar` `www.*****/index.php#profile` the content of my `Div` should be change.

**Note**

I used `document.location.hash` to get the value of `hash` like this :

```
<head>
 <script>
  var hashValue=document.location.hash;
  alert(hashValue);
 </script>
</head>
```

but it works only when user `goes back` and then `refresh the page`

Plz help me how can i achieve this :(

Comment: Use the [`hashchange` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/hashchange).

Comment: One thing you can do is add a call to the getLink() function on DOM ready. On DOM ready, inspect your URL and check for a string after the last '#' char. If this string isn't null, call `getLink(theString)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `hashchange` event:

```
function hash_changed() {
    var data = document.location.hash.substr(1);
    var box = document.getElementById("box");

    if (data) {
        // inner page
        box.innerHTML="This is " + data;
    }
    else {
        // homepage
        box.innerHTML = "";
    }
}

window.onhashchange = function () {
    hash_changed();
};

window.onload = function () {
    hash_changed();
};
```

Also when you are using `hashchange` event, there is
no need to set `onclick` for your links:

```
<a href="#home">Home</a>
<a href="#profile">Profile</a>
<a href="#message">Message</a>
<a href="#setting">Setting</a>
```

When user click on a link, the hash automatically changes (with `href` attribute of link),
and `hashchange` event get fired.

Check [DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/B8C8s/9/show) here.

---

#### First Time

When a user come to your page for the first time with a hash:

```
http://fiddle.jshell.net/B8C8s/9/show/#message
```

We must show the wanted page (`message` here), so we must run `hash_changed()` function
we declare above, at first time. For this, we must wait for DOM ready or `window.onload`.

Comment: yup it works but will it works in all major browser , i mean browsers compatible with only HTML4 ??

Comment: @AbarChoudhary Yes, it works in all browsers and IE8 and upper. And its interesting to know, IE8 is the first browser which introduce `hashchange` event `;)`.

Comment: hmm, then finally you gave me the Solution :* :D --

Answer (score 0):

Check the HTML5 history API. It allows you to work with the browser history

[HTML5 history api](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
     alert(location.hash);
});
```

or window.onhashchange event if you don't want to use jQuery

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be using AJAX, you'll really want to look into using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) instead of raw javascript unless your intention is educational. jQuery is just a mainstay of the web now.

**If you must use those hashes...**

Use [jQuery Special Events](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/jquery-special-events/), and use the `hashchange` event:

```
<a href='#home'>Home</a>
```

Script:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    $('#box').html("This is "+event.fragment);
});
```

**However, for your scenario...**

You don't need to use those `#` values at all as you're passing the values in your function arguments anyway according to the code you provided, just do this:

```
<a href="" onClick="getLink('Home');return false;">Home</a><br />
```

Alternatively (and preferably, as you're using AJAX according to the tags) you can use jQuery and its builtin selector click events which use [Event Listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener#Why_use_addEventListener.3F):

```
<a href='javascript:void();' class='divLink' id='home'>Home</a><br/>
```

Script is this easy:

```
$('.divLink').click(function(){
    $('#box').html("This is "+$(this).id());
}
```

Comment: dear ur 1st method will open the same page all time i click any link, and second method will consider it as one URL so there will be no history of which link was clicked before

Comment: @AbarChoudhary - Updated first answer. Try that.

Comment: There's a [demo too](http://jsfiddle.net/cowboy/wf4vF/) using the same methodology.